# wp-job-manager show expired offers at end of list

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure this out with no luck, on the ajax list I want to sort the listings so that expired ones are at the end.

I've tried to use this filter

```
add_filter ( 'get_job_listings_query_args', 'sort_by_expired' );

function sort_by_expired( $query_args ) {
  $today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));

  $query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
  $query_args['order'] = 'DESC';
  // $query_args['meta_key'] = '_job_expires';
  $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
    array(
      'key' => '_job_expires',
      // 'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
      // 'compare' => '>='
      )
  );

  return $query_args;
}
```

I've noticed that the code changes the order but not in the way I've would have wanted.

I tried to change different parameters (you can see the quoted out parts) changing:
**mata_value_num** to **meta_value** adding removing meta query parameters but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand you want to sort it by _job_expires ASC for the ones that are not expired and then display expired ones by DESC. this will have to be done in 2 separate queries. you can merge both arrays after that

edit: Merge 2 seperate queries' results as follows

```
//setup your queries as you already do
$query1 = new WP_Query($args_for_query1);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args_for_query2);

//create new empty query and populate it with the other two
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );

//populate post_count count for the loop to work correctly
$wp_query->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count;
```

Comment: Not exactly the sorting should be first the not expired ones and then the expired ones - this is the biggest hurdle right now for me

Comment: that's what i am saying. it's exactly what i wrote, make 2 queries, array_merge your results i edited to show you how to merge

Comment: sure thing, will put up the answer

Comment: well the merge should work (it merges one after the other) so you make 1 query for the unexpired ones, then 1 query for the expired ones, and merge results before the loop. should work. does it give you a different result?

Comment: I used the solution posted above - seemed simpler and does the job good enough to keep it that way

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work

```
  public function depcore_custom_orderby( $query_args ) {
    // Use meta_value_num for numeric sorting (if issues with meta_value)
    $query_args[ 'orderby' ] = 'meta_value';
    $query_args[ 'order' ] = 'DESC';
    return $query_args;
  }


  public function depcore_custom_orderby_query_args( $query_args ) {
    $query_args[ 'meta_key' ] = '_job_expires';
    return $query_args;
  }
```

Because I'm using the plugin boilerplate the filter call is used in the **plugin public** part

```
$this->loader->add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings_args', $plugin_public, 'depcore_custom_orderby', 99 );
$this->loader->add_filter( 'get_job_listings_query_args', $plugin_public,'depcore_custom_orderby_query_args', 99 );
```